# Input type="search" - not enable in Chrome

Tags: html, angularjs

My type = "search" does not enable the 'X' option to clear the imput in Chrome!
Any solution?

```
<div layout="row  text-left" style="float:left; width:100%;">
      <md-input-container flex-offset="15" flex="70">
         <label>Pesquisar...</label> 
           <input type="search" ng-model="$ctrl.pesquisa" ng-disabled="'@ViewBag.EditaConteudo'">
      </md-input-container>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works fine for the default input, i'd assume this is an issue with md. Check their issue tracker.

Comment: Yup, the material design styles seem to purposely hide it. `/* remove default appearance from all input/textarea */
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the rules of specificity you should be able to overcome this by doing the following:

```
<input type="search" class="my-search" ng-model="$ctrl.pesquisa" ng-disabled="'@ViewBag.EditaConteudo'">
```

Accompanied by the following CSS

```
input[type="search"].my-search {
  -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

input[type="search"].my-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

However, as others have pointed out, this is originally an issue with the css framework you are using rather than Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! Would you also have a solution for Internet Explorer?

Comment: @BrunoSouza I believe internet explorer responds to `input[type=search].my-search::-ms-clear { display: block; }`

Comment: @BrunoSouza Some SO elitist downvoted my answer so feel free to accept my answer if it was to any help :)